# How can I call Speech Recognition multiple times in 1 function?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, speech-recognition, annyang

I am relatively new to JavaScript and currently working a project a beginner probably shouldn't start on. I have been coding for some time in python and decided to give it a shot. I am trying to make a personal assistant, or as I like to call it, Jarvis (from IRON MAN). It currently can listen for commands and perform them just fine, however, I am trying to make a `send email` command that requires multiple input from a user all in one function. This send email function is technically in `parseCommand()` where I pass an identifier, known as i. I will eventually add more commands to `parseCommand()` and the identifier will help in knowing what command to perform. When I say, "jarvis send an email", `parseCommand("email")` is called. It is a promise because once it is done, I want to call annyang (command listener) again.

When "jarvis send an email" is triggered ->

```
"jarvis send an email" : async function(){
  annyang.abort(); // stop listening
  await parseCommand("email").then(annyang.start()); // Start listening for another command when done
}
```

parseCommand:

```
parseCommand(i){
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        recognition.stop();



        if(i == "email"){
            var SUBJECT;
            var TEXT;
            var TO;

            console.log("Running: send an email")
            await this.promptListen("Who shall I send it to?").then( async (email) =>{
                TO = email;
                console.log("got TO", TO)

                await this.promptListen("What shall the subject be?").then( async (subject) => {
                    SUBJECT = subject;
                    console.log("got SUBJECT", SUBJECT)

                    await this.promptListen("What would you like to say?").then((text) => {
                        TEXT = text;
                        console.log("got TEXT", TEXT)
                        resolve()
                        })
                    })
                });
            }
        })
    }
```

promptListen command:

```
promptListen(prompt){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            socket.emit("speak", prompt);
            setTimeout(1000);

            promptRecognition.stop(); // NOTE #1

            promptRecognition.start();

            promptRecognition.onresult = function(event){
                console.log(event)
                promptRecognition.stop();
                resolve(event.results[0][0].transcript);
            }
            promptRecognition.onnomatch = function() {
                promptRecognition.stop();
                reject(promptListen(prompt));
            }
        })

    }
```

The issue with the current functionality is that it doesn't work at all. I am prompted for the "Who shall I send it to?" and Jarvis listens. I get the TO console output, however, after that I get an error:

```
responses.js:63 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'start' on 'SpeechRecognition': recognition has already started.
    at Promise (http://localhost:3000/scripts/responses.js:63:31)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Respond.promptListen (http://localhost:3000/scripts/responses.js:57:16)
    at promptListen.then (http://localhost:3000/scripts/responses.js:41:28)
```

The error suggests that I am running SpeechRecognition already, however, I stop it at the start of `promptListen()` every time just in case. I do not know what is going on at all. The desired outcome would be that each call to `promptListen()` will allow me to prompt the user, listen to the response, store the response in a variable: for each variable needed in order to send the email (recipient, subject, and body). I am not familiar with JavaScript, promises, async, or await. I have tried every single variation possible as well as took a look at documentation to no avail. If I do not use promises, the `promptListen()` function is called at the same time for the recipient, subject, and body prompts. This is why I decided to try to resolve the issue with promises. Any help appreciated - Thank you!

Comment: `.then` accepts a *function* as parameter, not an *invoked function* (unless it's a higher order function that returns a function), did you mean `.then(() => annyang.start())` maybe?

Comment: that `parseCommand` code is taking the benefits of promises, and the added benefits of async/await, and just flushing them down the drain! - https://pastebin.com/NVs9UKxU is how that code should be written

Comment: I implemented your suggestions and both of them resulted in the same error. After playing with my code some more, I finally was able to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code works theoretically. The issue, or at least I think it is, is that when I call `then` `promptRecoginition.stop()` needs time to stop. I immediately call `.start()` again for the next prompt, once I resolve the recent `promptListen()`, therefore `promptRecognition` doesn't have time to `.stop()`. The solution that I have found to work is:

```
setTimeout( async () => {
    await this.promptListen("What shall the subject be").then( (subject) => {
        SUBJECT = subject;
        // Add another setTimeout here
    }
}, 1000);
```

Using the setTimeout function, I give `promptRecognition` time to `.stop()` and continue on without any errors.